# Read image XMP data in Python

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, xmp

Can I use PIL, like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764932/in-python-how-do-i-read-the-exif-data-for-an-image/4765242#4765242)?

I only need to **read** the data, and I'm looking for the easiest simplest way to do it *(I can't install **pyexiv**)*.

**edit:** I don't want to believe that the only way to do this is with some library ([python-xmp-toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/python-xmp-toolkit/), [pyexiv2](http://tilloy.net/dev/pyexiv2/doc/release-0.3.0/index.html), ...) that needs Exempi and Boost. There must be another option!

Answer (score 15):

Well, I was looking for something similar, then I came across the [PHP equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578169/how-can-i-read-xmp-data-from-a-jpg-with-php) question and I translated the answer to Python:

```
f = 'example.jpg'
fd = open(f)
d= fd.read()
xmp_start = d.find('<x:xmpmeta')
xmp_end = d.find('</x:xmpmeta')
xmp_str = d[xmp_start:xmp_end+12]
print(xmp_str)
```

you can then convert xmp_str and parse it with an XML API.

Comment: I like... always had problems with truncated keywords when using packages like PIL to access data. Another benefit is that reading it from the jpg results in no dependencies when writing a reusable package.

Comment: I had to open with 'rb' and find(b'<x:xmpmeta') and find('b</'x:xmpmeta'). Then it worked wonders at digging important metadata from DJI drone images.

Comment: XMP can now be in multiple separate pieces spread through the jpeg file, a condition this solution won't cope with.

Answer (score 11):

XMP metadata can be found in `applist`.

```
from PIL import Image
with Image.open(filename) as im:
    for segment, content in im.applist:
        marker, body = content.split('\x00', 1)
        if segment == 'APP1' and marker == 'http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/':
            # parse the XML string with any method you like
            print body
```

Comment: Nice, is that document anywhere? I only found https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/da8f2737a8a325ed5bb1d24a777a0b4d3ddaa7d8/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py#L57-L128

Comment: This won't always work as some jpeg files have the APP1 marker "XMP\0://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/" for some reason, and that \0 will break the split() function.

Comment: If there are no further nulls in the body, you could do `content.rsplit(b'\x00', 1)` and `b'http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/' in marker` instead.

Answer (score 3):

I am also interested to know if there is a 'proper' easy way to do this.

In the mean time, I've implemented reading XMP packets using pure Python in [PyAVM](https://github.com/astrofrog/pyavm). The relevant code is [here](https://github.com/astrofrog/pyavm/blob/master/pyavm/avm.py#L372). Maybe this would be useful to you?

Answer (score 2):

```
with open( imgFileName, "rb") as fin:
    img = fin.read()
    imgAsString=str(img)
    xmp_start = imgAsString.find('<x:xmpmeta')
    xmp_end = imgAsString.find('</x:xmpmeta')
    if xmp_start != xmp_end:
        xmpString = imgAsString[xmp_start:xmp_end+12]

    xmpAsXML = BeautifulSoup( xmpString )
    print(xmpAsXML.prettify())
```

Or you can use the Python XMP Toolkit

Comment: This will break when XMP is in multiple parts due to the jpeg format only allowing 64k for each chunk of such data.

Answer (score 1):

A search through the PIL source (1.1.7) tells me that it can recognize XMP information in Tiff files, but I cannot find any evidence of a documented or undocumented API for working with XMP information using PIL at the application level.

From the CHANGES file included in the source:

```
+ Support for preserving ICC profiles (by Florian Böch via Tim Hatch).

  Florian writes:

  It's a beta, so still needs some testing, but should allow you to:
  - retain embedded ICC profiles when saving from/to JPEG, PNG, TIFF.
     Existing code doesn't need to be changed.
  - access embedded profiles in JPEG, PNG, PSD, TIFF.

  It also includes patches for TIFF to retain IPTC, Photoshop and XMP
  metadata when saving as TIFF again, read/write TIFF resolution
  information correctly, and to correct inverted CMYK JPEG files.
```

So the support for XMP is limited to TIFF, and only allows XMP information to be retained when a TIFF image is loaded, possibly changed, and saved.  The application cannot access or create XMP data.

Answer (score 1):

Pillow (a PIL fork) can now return the xmpmetada in a dictionary invoking the method getxmp.

It works for png, jpeg and tif images since version 8.3.

Documentation can be found [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/plugins.html#PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile.getxmp).

Comment: This seemed to work for me, using code like:

`img = Image.open('/path/to/img.jpg')`
`img.getxmp()['xmpmeta']['RDF']['Description']['title']['Alt']['li']['text']`

Comment: Exactly... I'm doing the same!

Answer (score 0):

Shout out to [Chris Sherwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1558493/chris-sherwood) for the solution that I used. Came here to find a way to pull XMP data from DJI Drone Images. I too did not want to install Exempi. So, for posterity, I pulled these easier methods together for those people looking to extract values from XMP headers without a lot of hassle-

```
    # Extract XMP Data
    f = open(image_files[i], 'rb')
    d= f.read()
    xmp_start = d.find(b'<x:xmpmeta')
    xmp_end = d.find(b'</x:xmpmeta')
    xmp_str = d[xmp_start:xmp_end+12]

    # Extract Latitude
    search_str = b'Latitude="'
    value_start = xmp_str.find(search_str) + len(search_str)
    value_end = xmp_str.find(b'"',value_start)
    value = xmp_str[value_start:value_end]
    lat = value.decode('UTF-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

Basing on answers from @dirac, @Rich, @user1911091 and a note from @hippietrail, I came up with this solution. Not quite elegant but gets the data in case it is scattered:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open(self.filename, "rb")
d = f.read()
xmp_str = b""

while d:
    xmp_start = d.find(b"<x:xmpmeta")
    xmp_end = d.find(b"</x:xmpmeta")
    xmp_str += d[xmp_start : xmp_end + 12]
    d = d[xmp_end + 12 :]

xmpAsXML = BeautifulSoup(xmp_str)
print(xmpAsXML.prettify())
```

Answer (score 0):

As of PIL 8.2.0, this can be achieved with the [`getxmp()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/8.2.0.html#getxmp-for-jpeg-images) Image method. It does require `defusedxml` to be installed though.