# How to extract GPS location from HEIC files?

Tags: python-3.x, exif, heic

I use the following code to extract GPS location both from JPG and HEIC files:

```
#coding=utf-8
from PIL import Image
from urllib.request import urlopen
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS
from PIL.ExifTags import GPSTAGS

from pillow_heif import register_heif_opener

def get_exif(filename):
    image = Image.open(filename)
    image.verify()
    return image._getexif()

def get_geotagging(exif):
    if not exif:
        raise ValueError("No EXIF metadata found")

    geotagging = {}
    for (idx, tag) in TAGS.items():
        if tag == 'GPSInfo':
            if idx not in exif:
                raise ValueError("No EXIF geotagging found")

            for (key, val) in GPSTAGS.items():
                if key in exif[idx]:
                    geotagging[val] = exif[idx][key]

    return geotagging

register_heif_opener()

my_image='IMG_9610.HEIC'
#my_image='IMG_20210116_215317.jpg'

exif = get_exif(my_image)
labeled = get_geotagging(exif)
print(labeled)
```

This code works well with JPEG files, but returns the following error with HEIC:

```
AttributeError: _getexif
```

If I add the following function

```
def get_labeled_exif(exif):
    labeled = {}
    for (key, val) in exif.items():
        labeled[TAGS.get(key)] = val

    return labeled
```

and replace '_getexif()' with 'getexif()' then it works for both files, but the data is encrypted there - `'GPSInfo': 1234` and `get_geotagging()` doesn't work for such exif.

How could I fix it?

Comment: Share a HEIC file that is giving you problems, maybe? Dropbox or Google Drive etc.

Comment: How do you know that the HEIC file even contains the metadata you seek?

Comment: I updated my answer with a working code example for extracting GEO tagging info from a HEIC file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### **UPDATED POST 06-12-2022**

The code below is able to extract the GEO tagging information from a HEIC image file on my system.

```
from PIL import Image
from pillow_heif import register_heif_opener


def get_exif(filename):
    image = Image.open(filename)
    image.verify()
    return image.getexif().get_ifd(0x8825)


def get_geotagging(exif):
    geo_tagging_info = {}
    if not exif:
        raise ValueError("No EXIF metadata found")
    else:
        gps_keys = ['GPSVersionID', 'GPSLatitudeRef', 'GPSLatitude', 'GPSLongitudeRef', 'GPSLongitude',
                    'GPSAltitudeRef', 'GPSAltitude', 'GPSTimeStamp', 'GPSSatellites', 'GPSStatus', 'GPSMeasureMode',
                    'GPSDOP', 'GPSSpeedRef', 'GPSSpeed', 'GPSTrackRef', 'GPSTrack', 'GPSImgDirectionRef',
                    'GPSImgDirection', 'GPSMapDatum', 'GPSDestLatitudeRef', 'GPSDestLatitude', 'GPSDestLongitudeRef',
                    'GPSDestLongitude', 'GPSDestBearingRef', 'GPSDestBearing', 'GPSDestDistanceRef', 'GPSDestDistance',
                    'GPSProcessingMethod', 'GPSAreaInformation', 'GPSDateStamp', 'GPSDifferential']

        for k, v in exif.items():
            try:
                geo_tagging_info[gps_keys[k]] = str(v)
            except IndexError:
                pass
        return geo_tagging_info


register_heif_opener()

my_image = 'IMG_8362.heic'
image_info = get_exif(my_image)
results = get_geotagging(image_info)
print(results)
# x used to mask data
{'GPSLatitudeRef': 'N', 
'GPSLatitude': '(3x.0, 5x.0, 1x.0x)', 
'GPSLongitudeRef': 'W', 
'GPSLongitude': '(8x.0, 2x.0, 5x.2x)', 
'GPSAltitudeRef': "b'\\x00'", 
'GPSAltitude': '279.63243243243244', 
'GPSSpeedRef': 'K', 
'GPSSpeed': '0.04649941997239198', 
'GPSImgDirectionRef': 'T', 
'GPSImgDirection': '274.37165833514456', 
'GPSDestBearingRef': 'T', 
'GPSDestBearing': '27x.37165833514456', 
'GPSDateStamp': '2022:06:12'}
```

```
----------------------------------------
My system information
----------------------------------------
Platform:     Apple
OS Version:   macOS Catalina 10.15.7
Python: 3.9
Pillow: 9.1.1
pillow_heif: 0.3.0
----------------------------------------
```

### **ORIGINAL POST 06-11-2022**

The short answer is that [Pillow](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow) does not currently support the High Efficiency Image Format (HEIF) file format.

Reference:

- 2017: [Feature Request: Support HEIC](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2808)
- 2017: [Support for HEIF](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2806)
- 2020: [HEIF plugin](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/pull/4782)

One of the workarounds for this issue is [pyheif](https://github.com/carsales/pyheif).  This Python package has the functionality to covert a HEIC image to a JPEG one. After this transformation `Pillow` will be able to read the data from the image.

Another workaround for this format reading problem is [piexif](https://pypi.org/project/piexif/). Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64514225/add-date-taken-exif-xmp-information-to-tif-file-using-python/64654850#64654850) that I posted on converting a `TIFF` file to a JPEG one for reading with `Pillow`.

You could also use [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/), which reads HEIC files out of the box. Using it is slightly more complicated, because it requires using `subprocess`.

Comment: Thanks! But I can read the metadata from the HEIF file. The question is how to decode it. I don't want to wait for file conversion to JPG.

Comment: @LA_. I overlooked that section of the question.  Are you getting any keys or values for this `GPSTAGS.items()`?

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex thanks for the update.  what would be the way to get all the exif data instead of just gps.

Comment: @kristoph yes, this code can be modified to extract all the exif data.