# Reading a distant image with JavaScript and getting its metadata

Tags: javascript, ajax, jpeg, xmp

I want to read XMP metadata of a JPEG file in JavaScript. I found a way for PHP ([How can I read XMP data from a JPG with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578169/how-can-i-read-xmp-data-from-a-jpg-with-php)) and we can easily adapt it in JavaScript using AJAX, but the problem is : what about the distant images, those which are not on our server?

Thanks

Comment: Just send the url to the server, the server will download it and get the metadata.

Comment: if you are referring to files in the client's machine, you cannot access files from the client's machine using javascript. you'll need flash. or you can just send the file to the server for temporary storage then you can determine the metadata from the server side.

Comment: @Musa: I currently use this solution, but I would avoid PHP to have a JavaScript-only solution.

Comment: @rationalboss: No, sorry, my message was not totally clear, I want to read images stored on other servers, via its URL.

Comment: You cant due to Same Origin Policy

Comment: @Musa: And there are not another way to read a file's content?

Answer (score 0):

A starting point to read out metadata of an image with javascript is the library exif-js, which i found on github.

https://github.com/jseidelin/exif-js

Bad part is that it only focuses on Exif while XMP information won't be read out.