# How to get Panoramic Exif data in PHP?

Tags: php, exif, xmp

I am trying to read XMP-G Pano data from a panoramic image but its not returning complete Exif data. I am using this code.

```
$filename = 'panorama.jpeg';
$exif =  read_exif_data($filename, "EXIF");
foreach ($exif as $key => $value) {
    if(is_array($value)){
        foreach ($value as $vkey => $vvale) {
            echo $vvale;
        }
        echo "<br/>";
    }else{
        echo $value."<br/>";
    }
}
```

XMP-G Pano data can be seen when checking file from exifdata.com
[Check Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8hqf.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that because XMP is embedded into the image you can use an XML parser to get the information:

```
$content = file_get_contents($image);
$xmp_start = strpos($content, '<x:xmpmeta');
$xmp_end   = strpos($content, '</x:xmpmeta>');
$xmp_length = $xmp_end - $xmp_start;
$data = substr($content, $xmp_start, $xmp_length + 12);
$xmp = simplexml_load_string($xmp_data);
```

[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578169/how-can-i-read-xmp-data-from-a-jpg-with-php)