# Get GPS Metadata from DJI Drone Image

Tags: php

I am trying to get the GPS Metadata from a JPG image taken on a DJI Drone, specifically the Latitude, Longitude, and Altitude data.

[image: Windows Image Details Screenshot]

I have tried using the `exif_read_data('image.JPG');` function, however, only some of the tags show when I `var_dump` it.

This is the result:

> Warning: exif_read_data(RiverTone.JPG): Illegal IFD size: 2 + 0x615B*12 = 0x49046 > 0x5C75 in D:\Applications\XAMPP\htdocs\JURL\J360\test.php on line 3 array(35) { ["FileName"]=> string(13) "RiverTone.JPG" ["FileDateTime"]=> int(1601031254) ["FileSize"]=> int(16293169) ["FileType"]=> int(2) ["MimeType"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["SectionsFound"]=> string(30) "ANY_TAG, IFD0, EXIF, MAKERNOTE" ["COMPUTED"]=> array(6) { ["html"]=> string(26) "width="8192" height="4096"" ["Height"]=> int(4096) ["Width"]=> int(8192) ["IsColor"]=> int(1) ["ByteOrderMotorola"]=> int(0) ["ApertureFNumber"]=> string(5) "f/2.8" } ["ImageWidth"]=> int(8192) ["ImageLength"]=> int(4096) ["BitsPerSample"]=> array(3) { [0]=> int(8) [2](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtFOzCUMq745htJEkDoAkZ1U-dDCdQ?e=lXBjFp)=> int(8) [2](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtFOzCUMq745htJEkDoAkZ1U-dDCdQ?e=lXBjFp)=> int(8) } ["ImageDescription"]=> string(7) "default" ["Make"]=> string(3) "DJI" ["Model"]=> string(6) "FC3170" ["Orientation"]=> int(1) ["SamplesPerPixel"]=> int(3) ["XResolution"]=> string(4) "72/1" ["YResolution"]=> string(4) "72/1" ["ResolutionUnit"]=> int(2) ["Software"]=> string(11) "10.00.14.42" ["DateTime"]=> string(19) "2020:09:25 11:54:15" ["YCbCrPositioning"]=> int(1) ["ExposureTime"]=> string(4) "1/50" ["FNumber"]=> string(7) "280/100" ["ExposureProgram"]=> int(2) ["ISOSpeedRatings"]=> int(100) ["ExifVersion"]=> string(4) "0230" ["DateTimeOriginal"]=> string(19) "2020:09:25 11:54:15" ["DateTimeDigitized"]=> string(19) "2020:09:25 11:54:15" ["ComponentsConfiguration"]=> string(4) "" ["ExposureBiasValue"]=> string(4) "0/10" ["MaxApertureValue"]=> string(9) "2971/1000" ["MeteringMode"]=> int(1) ["LightSource"]=> int(0) ["Flash"]=> int(0) ["FocalLength"]=> string(9) "4500/1000" }

Here is a [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtFOzCUMq745htJEkDoAkZ1U-dDCdQ?e=lXBjFp) to the original file that I am using.

I would appreciate any suggestions that you might have.

Comment: Unfortunately not, that person was able to get the GPS data from their image using exif_read_data(). My image does not show any GPS data despite containing it. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: DJI is storing some information (e.g. position & gimbal) as XMP-metadata. Maybe the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578169) question can help you.